# Need to comma delimit json encoded query

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to add an autocomplete tokenizer script to some form fields and am having an issue with delimiting the values at the commas.

The way it is now if a person adds multiple values to the field the autocomplete suggestions will display them as one long value instead of each as an individual value. I first tried to explode the value before encoding it but it doesn't put it in the right format. Here's how it displays now:

```
[{"cb_activities":"Kicking Cats,"},{"cb_activities":"baseball,hockey,"}]
```

but I need it to display as:

```
[{"cb_activities":"Kicking Cats,"},{"cb_activities":"baseball,"},{"cb_activities":"hockey,"}]
```

Here's my php file:

```
<?
mysql_pconnect("localhost", "myuser", "mypass") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("mydb") or die("Could not select database");
$param = mysql_real_escape_string ($_GET["q"]);

$query = sprintf("SELECT DISTINCT cb_activities FROM jos_comprofiler WHERE cb_activities REGEXP '^$param'");
$arr = array();
$rs = mysql_query($query);

while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs))
{
    $arr[] = $obj;
}

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Here's the jquery script:
http://www.erecoverydev.com/autocomplete2/js/jquery.tokeninput.js

I haven't done much with json so please be specific lol.

Comment: What language is your code written in, and what are you currently using?

Comment: Script is jquery using a php file to pull the values from my db, not sure if I can post the entire script here or not but will try to add it.

Comment: why did you write "lol"?

Comment: You pasted the entire source code of an jQuery plug-in into your question? You could have just linked to it.

Comment: Ok, if the do's and dont's of posting are covered I would love to here some ideas on how to get the values to format correctly for the json encode.

Answer (score 0):

Unless im missing something you should be able to simply adjust your iteration:

```
$activities = array();
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs))
{
    $activities[] = array('cb_activities' => $obj->cb_activities);
}
```

However, I would just make `cb_activities` be an array and then `join` or `split` the array as necessary on the js side. for example:

```
$activities = array();

while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs))
{
    $activities[] = $obj->cb_activities;
}

echo json_encode(array('cb_activities' => $activities));
```

Then in your js you could to:

```
// assume data is the json returned by the server

var activities = data.cb_activities.join(',');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I see where you're going with it but I'm not quite sure how to implement it in my js file correctly. I assume I would just add the var activities = to the top just under the function, but then should I replace all of the li_data.cb_activities with li_activities? Everything I've tried so far with this method results in no field being displayed.

Comment: I'm wondering if I'm thinking about this all wrong, maybe I can just add an .split(',') somewhere in the mix here in the js and get the result i need?

Comment: ID idnt see your link to the JS till after you replied... My answer would ideally have the JS part of it run in the callback after of the ajax request to get the php results.

Comment: Is there a way I could add the comma delimiter here in this string? var queryStringDelimiter = settings.url.indexOf("?") < 0 ? "?" : "&";